# Can I install virtual environment in two separate directories?

Tags: python

Fact is I have already installed django. 
Now I want to install flask. But have no idea how to install virtual environment again in separate directory.

Comment: Do you need two or more virtual envs? is that?

Comment: Please check the documentation for virtualenv or venv - it is the whole point of virtual environments to have more than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the directory where you want your new virtual environment and type:

```sh
virtualenv venv
```

[Virutalenv documentation here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).